# Docker build / docker compose up error: Unknown desc = failed to fetch anonymous token: unexpected status: 401 Unauthorized

Tags: docker, nvidia-docker

When building a container (through docker build, docker run or docker-compose) using NVIDIA containers, I get the following error, somewhat randomly. When I usually start building the container, it works the first time. But next few times usually don't work.

```
------
 > [internal] load metadata for nvcr.io/nvidia/l4t-base:r32.5.0:
------
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: 
  failed to create LLB definition: failed to authorize: 
  rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to fetch anonymous token: unexpected status: 401 Unauthorized
```

My current workaround is to use a slightly different image **temporarily** whilst I’m adjusting other parts of the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### You have to `docker login nvcr.io`

Most of this is documented in the [setup docs](https://ngc.nvidia.com/setup), unfortunately `nvcr.io` doesn't have very good SEO or UX, so search results and most attempts don't show this page. This is, confusingly, different to [ngc catalog](https://catalog.ngc.nvidia.com/) / `docker login ngc.nvidia.com`.

- **Install NGC CLI:** (for macOS)

  - Run  `curl -O https://ngc.nvidia.com/downloads/ngccli_mac.zip && unzip ngccli_mac.zip && chmod u+x ngc`
  - `mv ngc /usr/local/bin/ngc`
- **Setup your environment:**

  - Create an account and get your API key from https://ngc.nvidia.com/
  - Add the API key to the CLI: `ngc config set`
  - Login to registry: `docker login nvcr.io`
- **Observe docker CLI output containing correct auth details:**

```
[auth] nvidia/tensorrt:pull,push token for nvcr.io
```

### Tips

Make sure you login to the right container registry. It's in the name of the docker image you are using. e.g.
`nvcr.io/nvidia/tensorrt:22.01-py3` uses `nvcr.io`.

### Explanation

With the benefit of hindsight, I understood `failed to fetch anonymous token: unexpected status: 401 Unauthorized`. I was not authenticated (or more correctly, I was authenticated to Docker Hub and NGC Catalog instead of **nvcr.io**). It was giving me an anonymous token, which hit the rate limit. I needed to create an account to get higher limits.

Comment: Thanks. I solved issue with this answer. I had a little difficulty to login to registry. Following contents helped me to login.

https://docs.nvidia.com/dgx/ngc-registry-for-dgx-user-guide/index.html

https://catalog.ngc.nvidia.com/

Comment: To get your API key, after login, click on the right top corner -> setup. get your API key

Comment: I had to chase up this as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71770693/error-saving-credentials-error-storing-credentials-err-exit-status-1-out

Answer (score 10):

Restarting docker server solved the issue

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: Thanks! It helped in my case. Was getting this error while building a tritonserver image.

### 
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to fetch anonymous token: unexpected status: 401 Unauthorized error: build failed
###

Answer (score 3):

If you happen to get this error and it has worked before, you probably have run into a download limit from nvcr. To circumvent it, it suffices to just **restart docker**.

For Docker desktop click on the docker icon in the taskbar and click restart.
Or on Mac your can use cmd + r.

[image: Docker Restart]

Comment: I don't think this would work, because the rate limit is server side, restarting software on your machine doesn't do anything. I think you've tricked yourself when debugging, the rate limit timeout finished.

Comment: Then maybe it was not the rate limit. But i waited for over an hour before I knew this trick and now it takes two minutes. I'll leave it here maybe it helps someone else.

Comment: Agree bouncing Docker worked for me too, NO idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Updating Docker from my version (4.5.0) to the latest version (4.9.0) helped me.

Comment: It could actually be a result of the docker service restart while you updated the version.