# Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `error getting credentials - err: exit status 1

Tags: docker, ubuntu, authentication, credentials

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and I have tried using `docker login` to log in in terminal, but got:

```
docker login 
Login with your Docker ID to push and pull images from Docker Hub. If you don't have a Docker ID, head over to https://hub.docker.com to create one.
Username: sfelshtyn
Password: 
Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out:` no usernames for https://index.docker.io/v1/``
```

Comment: Solution: 
I did a few steps: (You can find here: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/linux/)
gpg --generate-key
...

Comment: This ended up fixing it for me. I did have to first do `rm -rf ~/.password-store/docker-credential-helpers` to reset things and get it to work.

Comment: @StanislavFelshtyn I suggest that you put this as an answer.

Comment: Execute `gpg --generate-key` and then `pass init "<user-id>"` and then `docker login` should work. This at least works for me on Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: I installed docker using the desktop app installation, after removing it and installing via `apt` everything worked.

Answer (score 90):

Try to execute following command

```
service docker stop
rm ~/.docker/config.json
service docker start
```

then try docker login it will ask for username and password

for macos m2 following works

```
sudo chown -R $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.docker
```

Comment: [Related comment in a GH issue for reference](https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/issues/140#issuecomment-1149610603)

Comment: The m2 solution as well as the ubuntu solution worked for me. I do not know why this isn't the answer??

Comment: Unless you add the `credsStore` field back into your `.docker/config.json` after doing this, it's just storing the unencrypted base64 encoded password in your `.docker/config.json` file.

Answer (score 47):

I read [Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: pass store is uninitialized](https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/issues/140) to solve my problem, but none of them helped.

Then I switched to official docker documentation and found that I didn't go through the credentials management process during docker installation.

[I did a few steps](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/linux/):

1. `gpg --generate-key`
2. `pass init <generated gpg-id public key>`
3. `docker pull molly/privateimage`

After that I tried again docker login. I passed my personal data and it worked for me. I solved my issue.

Comment: Thanks! Definitely the answer that fixed my issue in the most proper way.
This wasn't necessary on macos but is on linux

Comment: Thanks, solves the issue for me on Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 23):

This worked for me -

```
pass remove -rf docker-credential-helpers
```

Answer (score 20):

1. Remove the key `credStore` from `~/.docker/config.json`, and everything works normal now.

   Before:

   ```
    {
        "auths": {},
        "credsStore": "desktop", // remove this line, irrespective of the value of credStore
        "currentContext": "desktop-linux"
    }
   ```

   After:

   ```
    {
        "auths": {},
        "currentContext": "desktop-linux"
    }
   ```
2. Remove `docker-credential-helpers`

   ```bash
   rm -rf ~/.password-store/docker-credential-helpers
   ```
3. Generate GPG Key Pair

   ```bash
   gpg --generate-key
   ```
4. Initialize `pass` utility, which is a password manager that uses GPG encryption for storing and managing passwords

   ```bash
   pass init <generated gpg-id public key>
   ```

References:

1. https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/issues/24#issuecomment-595692091
2. https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/issues/60#issuecomment-336748027

Comment: Works like a charm.
Followed step 1,3 and 4.

Comment: Same here, works like a charm. Thanks

Comment: I'm on windows and "credStore" was "desktop". I removed that and it helped a little but I still got the same error in the output of my remote commands

Comment: Update. I used this solution https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/4353#issuecomment-1801655306

Answer (score 10):

The following helped me:

1. `rm -rf ~/.password-store/docker-credential-helpers`
2. `gpg --generate-key`
3. `pass init <generated gpg-id public key>`

Comment: I passed in the wrong id :-( into "pass init [id]" and it gave me the error. This solved my problem!

Answer (score 6):

Just to add another solution taking from the other answers here.

If you've already started Docker Desktop and you're seeing the error:

```
error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `error getting credentials - err: exit status 1
```

Stop the application:

```
systemctl --user stop docker-desktop
```

If you've already followed the steps in [credentials-management-for-linux-users](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/get-started/#credentials-management-for-linux-users) , delete the existing pass key:

```
rm -rf ~/.password-store/docker-credential-helpers
```

Generate a new key and provide the correct credentials:

```
gpg --generate-key
```

> Note: make sure you set the correct email in the passkey you use to login into DockerHub. I used the wrong one, which was why Docker Desktop threw the error.

This will print out text like:

```
pub   rsa3072 2023-06-13 [SC] [expires: 2025-06-12]
      9F53995439D023FD
uid                      Your Name <Your Email>
sub   rsa3072 2023-06-13 [E] [expires: 2025-06-12]
```

Then use the `gpd-id` displayed within the `pub` section to initialise `pass`, e.g.:

```
pass init 9F53995439D023FD
```

Finally, start Docker Desktop:

```
systemctl --user start docker-desktop
```

Hope this helps!

---

**UPDATE**: I also ran into problems logging into AWS ECR on Ubuntu with the error:

```
Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `exit status 1: gpg: public key of ultimately trusted key 9F53995439D023FD not found
gpg: public key of ultimately trusted key 7F525559F4750A05 not found
gpg: public key of ultimately trusted key 3D39C9F57C3C2E11 not found
gpg: public key of ultimately trusted key DCB9A14562B73138 not found
gpg: public key of ultimately trusted key 91B3075B62503284 not found
Password encryption aborted.``
```

I was able to fix the issue and login to ECR by following the steps in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/m-rey/b981b214a8936e889dc3675557ad5b22). I'll reproduce them below in case the gist is deleted in the future:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

gpg --check-trustdb 2>&1| grep 'not found' | awk '{print $8}' >bad-keys.txt
gpg --export-ownertrust > ownertrust-gpg.txt
mv ~/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg ~/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg-broken
for KEY in `cat bad-keys.txt` ; do sed -i "/$KEY/d" ownertrust-gpg.txt ; done
gpg --import-ownertrust ownertrust-gpg.txt
rm bad-keys.txt ownertrust-gpg.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it as below for windows machine,

1. Go to your `C://Users/YOUR_USER_FOLDER`
2. Get inside `.docker` folder
3. Remove `config.json` file
4. Try login again and it succeeded.

Answer (score 2):

It's worked for me

```
service docker stop
rm ~/.docker/config.json
rm /usr/local/bin/docker-credential-pass
service docker start
```

Basically, you need to remove your credentials from your local environment,(These two rm ~ commands do this work)

If you are having permission issues, use sudo

Answer (score 2):

After trying all of the above method, the issue still persists, use your `email id` to login rather than your `username`

Answer (score 2):

No one of these answers seemed to work for me by itself, so I'll share the exact steps I took to get this working in case it helps someone else:

```
# clear out old config file
rm ~/.docker/config.json
<restart docker desktop>
# clear out and generate fresh gpg keys
pass remove -rf docker-credential-helpers
gpg --generate-key
pass init <keyid>
```

It's possible that the second set of commands (clearing out and setting up new gpg key) would have worked without clearing out the docker config, but I can say at the very least that clearing out the old config was not sufficient, as the (current) top solution to this question ([by Tanjin Alam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74624600/177677)) had suggested.

Answer (score 2):

The real answer is you need to use Sudo . Nvidia docs say docker but many cases docker doesnt have permission to login and store if not running as root.
THis was my case in WSL2 Unbuntu under windows 11

Answer (score 2):

1. first stop docker with this command

   `service docker stop`
2. remove old docker config

   `rm ~/.docker/config.json`
3. start docker

   `service docker start`
4. and then login

   `docker login`

Answer (score 1):

On mac with intell

I did

```
sudo chown -R $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.docker
```

Then changed in file ~/.docker/config.json

The “credsStore” was “desktop” and I changed it to “osxkeychain”.

It works for me

Answer (score 0):

When you run the gpg command. Then while running the pass init command, pass the pub key generated on the the output of gpg command.

`$ pass init <pub key from gpg command>`

Answer (score 0):

I changed the value of "credsStore" to "wincred" in config.json and I was able to login with my windows credential

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused when you use `sudo gpg --generate-key` in setting up pass.
You will have to remove the saved credentials first `sudo rm -rf ~/.password-store/docker-credential-helpers` `sudo rm /root/.docker/config.json` then do `gpg --generate-key` and `pass init <generated-key>` then attempt `docker login` again.

Answer (score 0):

for macos m2 following worked for me

```
sudo chown -R $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.docker
```