Login DockerHub via Jenkins to push an image
I have build an image using jenkins and now I wanted to push the same image into docker hub.
For this I have to login to the same and getting this error again and again
Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: pass not initialized: exit status 1: Error: password store is empty. Try "pass init".
enter image description here
While I am trying to login to the dockerhub via terminal I am not getting any error but here in jenkins I am getting this.
docker login
Authenticating with existing credentials...
Login Succeeded
Tried to initialize the password multiple times and able to login via terminal but in jenkins it is not working

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

This is imilar question here I think. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71770693/error-saving-credentials-error-storing-credentials-err-exit-status-1-out

why don't you vault the credentials in Jenkins vault and try using them in pipeline?.
